# Deploying composer-rest-server api on ibm cloud -CARD NOT FOUND - {$PORT}

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I'm trying to deploy a composer-rest-server on IBM cloud, unfortunately, I'm facing many errors and so far I couldn't find solutions online.

I used this tutorial for the deployment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-deploy-blockchain-starter-plan-network/index.html

1. I'm not using the sample artifacts, I'm connecting to my own artifacts.

The first error I face is that when **I run thcommand:** : 
`cf login -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net --sso`
**and then** : `cf push car-auction --docker-image ibmblockchain/composer-rest-server:0.19.5 \-c "composer-rest-server -c admin@carauction-network -n never -w true" \-i 1 -m 256M --no-start --no-manifest`

I have this **error**: `No org targeted, use 'cf target -o ORG' to target an Org.
FAILED`.

Well after some research I figure another way to solve this which goes like that: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/166972/no-org-and-space-targeted-use-cf-target-o-org-s-sp.html
1.`cf api https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net`
2.`cf login`

So finally I have org and space already defined. Moving on ...

3.Repeat **the following command** : `cf push car-auction --docker-image ibmblockchain/composer-rest-server:0.19.5 \-c "composer-rest-server -c admin@carauction-network -n never -w true" \-i 1 -m 256M --no-start --no-manifest`

the output looks fine :

```
    Getting app info...
```

Updating the app with these attributes...
  name:                xxxx
  docker image:        ibmblockchain/composer-rest-server:0.19.5
  command:             composer-rest-server -c admin@xxxx -n never -w true
  disk quota:          1G
  health check type:   port
  instances:           1
  memory:              256M
  stack:               cflinuxfs2
  env:
    NODE_CONFIG
  routes:
    xxxx.eu-gb.mybluemix.net

Updating app xxxx...
Mapping routes...

name:              xxxx
requested state:   stopped
routes:            xxxx.eu-gb.mybluemix.net
last uploaded:     Fri 24 Aug 15:44:21 CEST 2018
stack:
docker image:      ibmblockchain/composer-rest-server:0.19.5

type:            web
instances:       0/1
memory usage:    256M
start command:   composer-rest-server -c admin@xxxx -n never -w
                 true

There are no running instances of this process.

4. I run this : `cf set-env xxxx NODE_CONFIG "${NODE_CONFIG}"`

earlier on the tutorial, I did the export already with the local card-store file.

5. Finally when I run: `cf start car-auction`
   I got the big error or rather the multiple errors.

In the beginning I had an error like that :

```
An application must be listening on the right port. Instead of hardcoding the port, use the $PORT environment variable
```

well Idk why but sometimes the error change for "card not found, the installation fails etc...

well I do composer-rest-server and I use the exact same card I'm using on the deployment and it works perfectly. It seems not stable at all and I'm sincerely blocked on that.
If someone knows how to deal with all that I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend asking directly in the comment section below that [referenced tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-deploy-blockchain-starter-plan-network/index.html). The authors are responding to questions and there is a technical discussion.

In your case it seems that the tutorial has been updated which fixed an issue.